# PHP 7 Error with ChannelImages: Fatal error: 'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in…

Tags: ee2, php, channel-images, ee2-upgrades

I'm getting this error when trying to upload an image with ChannelImages 5.4.19 with EE 2.11.7:

> Fatal error:  'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in
>   /home/omart/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_images/ajax.channel_images.php
>   on line 2442

The offending code is below. Line 2442 is the line with continue;.

```
if ($field_type == 'file') {
        $img_path = str_replace($file_dirs_search, $file_dirs_replace, $field_data);

        if (file_exists($img_path) == FALSE) {
            exit($img_path);
            continue;
        }

        $img = array();
        $img['path'] = $img_path;
        $images[] = $img;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `continue` with `return` statement.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, and it resulted in a slew of additional PHP errors.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the resulting errors are from the same issue just further down the PHP code.